# CircleCI build to cPanel gets "does not appear to be a git repository" error

Tags: git, github, yaml, cpanel, circleci

I am trying to push code from my local->cPanel using cPanel git version control.

I'm pushing my code to github and when I merge my branch, it kicks off a a build in CircleCI. My build errors out, and I'm not sure why.

It's saying that the remote does not appear to be a git repository, but when I perform this push directly from my local to cPanel, it works fine.

Things I've tried.

- Added SSH private key to CircleCI and added it to my build script
  with`add_ssh_keys`
- Added the public ssh key to cPanel and authorized it.

`.circleci/config.yml`

```
...
deploy-staging:
    machine:
      enabled: true

    working_directory: ~/home/


    steps:

      - checkout

      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "MY:FI:NG:ER:PR:IN:T"

      - run:
          name: Setup and checkout Staging branch
          command: |
            #  Add user
            git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
            git config --global user.name "me"
            #  Add cPanel remotes
            git remote add my-staging ssh://my@email.com:7822/home/staging
            git remote -v
            git checkout -B staging
            # Use specific ignore file
            mv .gitignore-cpanel .gitignore
            # User specific cpanel.yml file 
            mv .cpanel-staging.yml .cpanel.yml
            mv robots-staging.txt robots.txt


      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-artifacts-{{ .Revision }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-artifacts-

      - run:
          name: Commit the changes to git
          command: |
            # Add all code, including ignored artifacts
            git add .
            # Include build number in commit message
            git commit --message="Deploying CircleCI build $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM to cPanel staging"

      - run:
          name: Deploy staging branch to cPanel Staging master branch using git push
          command: git push my-staging staging:master --force
...
```

So when I run this, I receive this error

```
$ #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
git push my-staging staging:master --force

fatal: 'my-staging' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Exited with code 128
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

I had the `working_directory` set incorrectly, which was causing permission errors and ultimately not allowing me to connect. Make sure this `dir` is set to same path as the remote.